# Get aggregate data from SQL tables with a one to many lookup relationship without altering the table

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I need summary information from a table of data where there are multiple IDs for each item that map onto unique real names available in a lookup table.

I have a working solution that relies on altering the data table with a new column:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/1f224/7

Is there a way to get unit sums grouped by real_name and region without altering the data table?

The structure of the data table (region_data) is:

| item_code | short_code | region | units |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B2513-70 | Brash | East | 18 |
| C2692-59 | Scope | East | 100 |
| C2692-59 | Scope | North | 94 |
| A6152-94 | Chunk | South | 70 |
| C2692-59 | Scope | West | 40 |
| A4891-91 | Topic | East | 65 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

`item_code` is the link to the lookup.

The lookup table (`item_lookup`) is:

| item_code | real_name |
| --- | --- |
| B2513-70 | Oven |
| C2692-59 | Oven |
| F6940-84 | Music |
| A4891-91 | Music |
| E6031-11 | Music |
| B2007-23 | Hotel |
| D6228-48 | Hotel |
| F3679-48 | Ladder |
| E3587-36 | Ladder |
| A6152-94 | Ladder |

In this example, there are 10 unique item_codes that map onto 4 unique items (based on `real_names`).

My working example requires 3 steps:

**Step 1**: alter region_data to add a column for real_name

```sql
-- # add column to region_data
ALTER TABLE region_data
ADD COLUMN rn text;
```

**Step 2**: update region_data rn column with real_name from item_lookup

```sql
-- # add real_name as rn to region_data from item_lookup
update 
    region_data rd
set
    rn = lu.real_name
from
    item_lookup lu
where
    rd.item_code = lu.item_code;
```

**Step 3**: Create the desired summary output

```sql
-- # create the summary table by real_name, region
select 
    rn,
    region, 
    sum(units)
from 
    region_data
group by
    rollup(rn, region)
```

Again is there a way to make the link between `item_codes` and `real_name` in a query that does not rely on altering the `region_data` table?

Comment: Have you tried a JOIN ?

Comment: Yes. See my answer below. I was overcomplicating it by wanting to have the joining field in the select which breaks the ability to group by the fields I am interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as I posted, I came up with this which works:

```sql
select 
    rd.region region,
    lu.real_name name,
    sum(units)
from 
    region_data rd
join
    item_lookup lu
on 
    lu.item_code = rd.item_code
group by
    rollup(name, region)
order by
    region;
```

I had a block on not having item_code in the select.